# How to get Neo4JClient to perform a bulk insert

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

When running the following code I receive an exception "CypherTypeException: Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties." - What am I doing wrong, and what needs to change to make it work?

```
        var wordObjs = new List<object>();
        foreach (string word in WordGroups.GetAllWords())
        {
            wordObjs.Add(new { Value = word});
        }
        GraphClient.Cypher
            .Create("(word:Word {words})")
            .WithParam("words", new { words = wordObjs})
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `var wordObjs = new List<object>();` to `var wordObjs = new List<string>();` - hmm now I see why that won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be use a concrete class

```
private class Value { 
    public string Value {get;set;} 
}
```

and use `new List<Value>()` instead, I think the client is having trouble with the anonymous nature of your `List`.

Comment: It kind of detracts from the no-schema concept a bit but it works, so thanks :)

Comment: The problem is not with the DB not being able to handle it, but more the client itself, hopefully we'll be able to use things like `dynamic` soon which should get around this.